# CPLEX C++: Avoid variable being added to BOTH variable arrays

Tags: c++, cplex

I have two `IloNumVarArrays`, called `p` and `p_old`. I would like to save the current state  in `p_old` and add new variables to `p` (but only to `p` because `p_old` should be a back-up). But when I add new variables to `p`, and add them to my model, they are added to `p_old` as well. I would like to avoid them being added to `p_old`, as my intention is to save the state of variables I have before the modification in `p_old`. Here's an example.

```
#include <vector>
#include <ilcplex/ilocplex.h>
ILOSTLBEGIN

int main(){
  
  bool solved;

  // vector R contains all requests
  std::vector <int> R = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};

  int new_request;
  
  // use this stringstream to create variable and constraint names
  std::stringstream name;

  IloEnv             env;
  IloModel     model(env);
  IloNumVarArray p(env,R.size());
  IloConstraintArray accept(env,R.size());
  IloNumVarArray p_old(env, R.size());
  for (const auto& i: R)
  {
    name << "p_" << i;
    p[i] = IloNumVar(env, 0, 1, ILOBOOL, name.str().c_str()); 
    name.str("");
    p_old[i] = p[i];
  }


  
  IloExpr expr(env);
  // Create objective function
  for (const auto& i : R)
  {
      expr += p[i]; 
  }
  IloObjective obj(env, expr, IloObjective::Minimize);
  model.add(obj);
  expr.clear();
  
  env.out() << endl << p << endl;
  env.out() << endl << p_old << endl;
  // Create the solver object
  IloCplex cplex(model);
  env.out() << "Before" << endl;
  env.out() << model << endl;
  cplex.exportModel("Before.lp");
  
  solved = cplex.solve();
  if (solved)
  {
    // If CPLEX successfully solved the model, print the results
    std::cout << "\n\nCplex success!\n";
    std::cout << "\tStatus: " << cplex.getStatus() << "\n";
    std::cout << "\tObjective value: " << cplex.getObjValue() << "\n";

    // remove p_1 and p_2 from model
    p[1].end();
    p[2].end();
    
    // add new request to R, create variable p and corresponding constraint
    new_request = 11;
    R.push_back(new_request);
    name << "p_" << new_request;
    p.add(IloNumVar(env,0,1,ILOBOOL,name.str().c_str()));
    name.str("");

    
    new_request = 12;
    R.push_back(new_request);
    name << "p_" << new_request;
    p.add(IloNumVar(env,0,1,ILOBOOL,name.str().c_str()));
    name.str("");

    accept.add(2, IloRange());
    accept[11] = IloRange(env,1,p[11],1,"accept_11");
    accept[12] = IloRange(env,1,p[12],1,"accept_12");
    model.add(accept[11]);
    model.add(accept[12]);

    env.out() << endl << p << endl;
    env.out() << endl << p_old << endl;

    env.out() << "After" << endl;
    env.out() << model << endl;
    cplex.exportModel("After.lp");
    solved = cplex.solve();
  }
  
  expr.end();
  env.end();
}
```

The reason behind the whole thing is that I have a larger model for a dial-a-ride problem, which receives new requests and is solved every time a new request arrives. When this happens variables and constraints corresponding to the new request are added. However, it may take no more than 10 seconds to add all of those variables and constraints, as the requests have to receive an answer quickly. If it happens that modifying the model hasn't finished after 10 seconds, the request is rejected, i.e. all of the previously added variables and constraints are not needed any more and I don't want to have them in the model. That's where I need the `IloNumVarArray p_old`, so that after a timed out modification I can go back to the old state using

```
p.end_elements();
p.add(p_old.getSize(), IloNumVar());
for (const auto& i: R)
{
    p[i] = p_old[i];
}
```

or something similar... Anybody any ideas? Help is very much appreciated!

Comment: you are calling `p_old[i] = p[i];` just after setting `p[i]`. is that intended?

Comment: Yes, that is intended. Before adding variables p_11 and p_12 to p, p and p_old should contain the same variables. After adding p_11 and p_12 to p, only p should contain p_11 and p_12 but p_old shouldn't.

Comment: It looks like `IloNumVarArray` is using the underlying array `env`. Can you try to make an explicit copy?

Comment: Is it possible to make explicit copies of `IloNumVarArray`? If yes, that would solve my problem. But it seems that `IloNumVarArray` is actually a 'handle' pointing to an 'implementation object' (this is how it is described in the CPLEX C++ Reference Manual I think). So when I copy an object of `IloNumVarArray`, I just have a second pointer to the same implementation object. What I would have to do, is create a copy of the implementation object but I don't know how...

Comment: you could try `IloNumVarArray p_old; p_old.add(p);`

Comment: Apparently there is a function `IloGetClone()` (I haven't tried it yet but it seems promising).